# lxml parsing xml, missing root error

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml, utf-16

I'm trying to parse an xml file so that i can operate on the data contained in it.

It's 9 million lines long, so I won't post it.

Here is my code:

```
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(recover = True, encoding = 'utf-16')

tree = etree.parse('xml_parts.xml', parser)

ns = {'d': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'}

tree.find('d:database', ns)
```

Here is the first section of the xml file (it is utf-16 encoded but that is not specified in the header):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mysqldump xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<database name="parts_bbdb">
  <table_structure name="parts">
    <field Field="part_id" Type="int(11)" Null="NO" Key="PRI" Extra="auto_increment" Comment="" />
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./AtomParse", line 13, in <module>
tree.find('{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}database')
File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 2208, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.find (src/lxml/etree.c:68635)
File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 1876, in lxml.etree._ElementTree._assertHasRoot (src/lxml/etree.c:65215)
AssertionError: ElementTree not initialized, missing root
```

I have never parsed XML before, but from reading the lxml documentation I thought this should work.

I know the overall structure of the XML file, and once I am able to access the attributes at an element I will be fine with it, but there have been some teething issues.

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great, thanks!

Edit:

```
<row>
    <field name="part_id">2557</field>
    <field name="ok">0</field>
    <field name="part_name">BBa_S01288</field>
    <field name="short_desc">Intermediate part from assembly 236</field>
    <field name="description" xsi:nil="true" />
    <field name="part_type">Intermediate</field>
    <field name="author">Randy Rettberg</field>
    <field name="owning_group_id">7</field>
    <field name="status">Deleted</field>
    <field name="dominant">0</field>
    <field name="informational">0</field>
    <field name="discontinued">1</field>
    <field name="part_status"></field>
    <field name="sample_status">Discontinued</field>
    <field name="p_status_cache"></field>
    <field name="s_status_cache"></field>
    <field name="creation_date">2003-12-03</field>
    <field name="m_datetime">2015-05-08 14:14:17</field>
    <field name="m_user_id">0</field>
    <field name="uses">0</field>
    <field name="doc_size">686</field>
    <field name="works"></field>
    <field name="favorite">0</field>
    <field name="specified_u_list">_149_156_603_145_193_147_161_603_145_</field>
    <field name="deep_u_list">_149_156_603_145_193_147_161_603_145_</field>
    <field name="deep_count">9</field>
    <field name="ps_string" xsi:nil="true" />
    <field name="scars"></field>
    <field name="default_scars"></field>
    <field name="owner_id">24</field>
    <field name="group_u_list">_1_</field>
    <field name="has_barcode">0</field>
    <field name="notes" xsi:nil="true" />
    <field name="source"></field>
    <field name="nickname"></field>
    <field name="categories">//classic/intermediate/uncategorized</field>
    <field name="sequence">tcacacaggaaa</field>
    <field name="sequence_sha1">÷?¾TŸ]°f ÜèÕ?]Mò</field>
    <field name="sequence_update">5</field>
    <field name="seq_edit_cache">&lt;script
```

In the above code, I believe the encoding issues are from the 3rd line from bottom in "sequence_sha1". There are 400000 blocks like this each with one line like this.

Comment: Please edit the above and include the full exception. Are you sure the parse was successful - try `print(lxml.etree.tostring(tree))`

Comment: I've added the full exception, also trying the print statement results in 
    File "./AtomParse", line 12, in <module>
    print(lxml.etree.tostring(tree))
    NameError: name 'lxml' is not defined

Comment: There must be something wrong with your xml, it is not parsing correctly because I cannot replicate your issue, try `print(etree.tostring(tree))` you will probably find it is `None`. Note: your namespace definition is incorrect `d:database` - `database` is not in the `xsi` namespace just use `database` in your find.

Comment: If i remove the utf-16 encoding argument, I get this error: 
    lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate 
    encoding !
    Bytes: 0xF7 0x3F 0xBE 0x18, line 104, column 31

Comment: The file contains information for about 40,000 different biological parts, each part has one line that is incorrectly encoded (the first being at 104, generating that error), the second being about another 100 lines down, and so on for 40,000 parts. I'll add the first part in so you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: The print(etree.tostring(tree)) does return none (only when I keep the utf-16 argument in - otherwise I get the error I commented above), followed by the original error I posted. I am also quite sure there are errors in the xml file. I pulled it from here http://parts.igem.org/Registry_API (down the bottom of the page).

Comment: I think a major problem is that there is no `encoding="UTF-16"` in the XML file. The encoding has to be specified unless it is UTF-8.

Answer (score -1):

You can check carefully if the file is not damaged.  Be aware that if some lines do not end normally, this may be the cause of this error. I mean the 6.row: <field name="description" xsi:nil="true" />; 8th row from the bottom  <field name="notes" xsi:nil="true" /> etc.

Comment: As long as there is an in-scope declaration of the `xsi` namespace prefix, there is nothing wrong with `<field name="description" xsi:nil="true" />` or `<field name="notes" xsi:nil="true" />`.